# How to set first day of week as Tuesday in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to set the first day of the week as Tuesday in pandas using this **pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek((Tuesday =0,Monday=6))**. I am getting this 
**ERROR: 'Series' object is not callable**, can someone help me to figure out this issue.

Comment: Can you add data sample? Maybe need `df['col'].dt.dayofweek`

Comment: yup @jezrael I tried with that one but same error

Comment: OK, check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Best I can do for you is:

```
tidx = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=7)

(tidx.dayofweek - 2) % 7

Int64Index([5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
```

---

Or define a subclass

```
class DTI(pd.DatetimeIndex):
    @property
    def dayofweek(self):
        return (super().dayofweek - 2) % 7

dti = DTI(tidx)

dti.dayofweek

Int64Index([5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
```